# why kernel sent RST to a remote TCP server after the machine receiving a SYN/ACK packet?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I use raw socket to build a tcp client program and run it on machine A
and I run a regular tcp server program on machine B

the raw socket-based client program first send a SYN packet
and then it receives a SYN/ACK packet from the remote tcp server
then the kernel of machine A sends a RST to the remote tcp server

the sequence number and ack-sequence number is fine
what are potential reasons?
and how to deal with it? thanks!

BTW: I used tcpdump to capture packets on the remote machine B
and it shows "TCP port numbers reused" for the SYN packet from client,
actually before the client send the SYN, I used

```
netstat -tnp
```

to check on-going tcp sessions, and it shows nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. If a machine receives a SYN/ACK packet it doesn't expect, it should respond with a RST to let the other side know that it has no knowledge of or interest in that connection. The kernel sent a RST because that's what it's supposed to do -- it has no idea what your program is doing.

If you're trying to run your own TCP stack on a machine that already has a TCP stack, you'll have to prevent the regular TCP stack from responding to machines your stack is trying to talk to -- otherwise, they'll be talking to two TCP stacks which can't possibly work.

Comment: but I use raw socket to send a SYN and I used libpcap function to wait for the incoming SYN/ACK packet. so, how to make the kernel know that the client program is waiting for a SYN/ACK? thanks!

Comment: @user138126: You also need to do something to stop the kernel from seeing the responses. Exactly what depends on the platform -- may be a firewall rule? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306386/packet-data-intercept-and-modification)

Comment: wow, it is complex, so I can just drop the rst by a command line. but the problem is why on the server side, it sees the first SYN packet as port reused? on the server side, there is no raw socket and it has only 1 tcp stack

Comment: @user138126: Most likely because you keep reusing the same ports and ISNs and violating TCP rules left and right leaving the other end's TCP stack in an unusual state.