# Modify TCP/IP packets live

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I wish to be able to be able to make a small modification to all the packets that are being sent from my computer - specifically, TCP packets (though just IP would also be fine, as I'll do the parsing myself).

I've tried looking for existing tools but couldn't find any that would allow me to modify the packets in real-time.

I've thought that a tool that would allow me to create a "fake" adapter so i'll be able to connect to it and it will act as a transparent proxy, but couldn't find any tool that might work for me and allow me to actually change the packets live.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306386/packet-data-intercept-and-modification

Comment: Seems exactly what I'm looking for, can't believe I've missed it. Checking it  now.